# How can I add newlines to stringstream or a string using returns rather than '\n'?

Tags: c++

I have a file. Rather than using ifstream, I want to hard code it into my .cpp file. However, it is formatted using returns rather than "\n" characters. Is there a solution for this? I don't want to manually convert everything to "\n".

```
stringstream newString;
newString = "Nine of Spades
Ten of Spades
Jack of Spades
Queen of Spades
King of Spades
Ace of Spades
Nine of Hearts
...
Ace of Diamonds";
```

Comment: What about std::endl ?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Irrelvant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C++11 or later, you can use a raw string literal:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream newString{
R"(Nine of Spades
Ten of Spades
Jack of Spades
Queen of Spades
King of Spades
Ace of Spades
Nine of Hearts
...
Ace of Diamonds)" };

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/618e11dc703b4415)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
stringstream newString(R"raw(Nine of Spades
Ten of Spades
Jack of Spades
Queen of Spades
King of Spades
Ace of Spades
Nine of Hearts
...
Ace of Diamonds)raw");
```

See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed8907639e0b4847).